# Duplicate keys error after switching to MySQL Galera

Tags: mysql, galera

I recently switched from a single MySQL installation to MySQL Galera, running on 3 nodes addressed via HAProxy. Ever since switching I do get randomly "duplicate key" errors reported which theoretically should not be possible as I do check if the dataset is already available.

e.g.:

```
MySQL Error executing stmt:

        INSERT INTO user_ips
            (user_id,ip) 
        VALUES
            ('444079','41.205.7.198, 176.9.19.101')


 Error No:  1062
 Error:         Duplicate entry '444079-41.205.7.198, 1' for key 'user_id'
```

My code looks like this:

```
function save_user_ip($user_id){
    global $T62, $link;
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // do we already know that user by this ip?
    $stmt="
        SELECT ID AS ip_id
        FROM $T62
        WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND ip = '$ip'
    ";
    $row = db_get_row2($stmt);
    $ip_id = isset($row->ip_id) ? $row->ip_id : "";

    if (!$ip_id){ // ip unknown for that user, save it
        $stmt="
            INSERT INTO $T62
                (user_id,ip) 
            VALUES
                ('$user_id','$ip')
        ";
        db_query($stmt);
        $ip_id = db_insertid($link);
    }       
    return $ip_id;
}
```

Running this on a test page it works as intended. On the production server under load it however does not always work. I thought about INSERT IGNORE but would rather not run an insert on all actions as writes are slower and it also triggers a warning.

Running `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` creates following output:
1146 - Table 'tablename' doesn't exist

One possible solution that seems to work at least on development cluster:

```
// save ip. Will ignore if already known ip
$stmt="
    INSERT IGNORE INTO $T62
        (user_id,ip) 
    VALUES
        ('$user_id','$ip')
";
#echo $stmt; exit;
db_query($stmt);
$ip_id = db_insertid($link);
// if ip already known, retrieve it
if (!$ip_id){ 
    $stmt="
        SELECT ID AS ip_id
        FROM $T62
        WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND ip = '$ip'
    ";
    $row = db_get_row2($stmt);
    $ip_id = $row->ip_id;
}   
return $ip_id;
```

Not sure how this improves the situation on prod or if it makes things even worse. There might be a more elegant solution.

Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` and add the output in the question. Have you tried using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` instead of running 2 queries (one to check and another to insert)?

Comment: If the unique or primary key is `(user_id,ip)`, you could also just use only the `INSERT` and simply change your application to ignore duplicate key errors (no need to do that first SELECT at all!)

Comment: *"writes are slower"*. True but there won't be any write when there is a duplicate error. Did you test if that route is slower or faster?

Comment: I tried the IGNORE solution (altered question). That works, just not sure if this is better or worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User error.

Since when does an `ip` look like `41.205.7.198, 176.9.19.101`?

`444079-41.205.7.198, 1` implies that `41.205.7.198, 1` was what was used as the `ip`.  That's the first 15 characters, so I guess you have `VARCHAR(15)`.  (Note: this is why the *first* comment was asking for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

So, your funny IP got truncated, leading to a user-caused DUP KEY.

Comment: IPv6 is upon us; switch to `VARCHAR(39) CHARACTER SET ascii`.

Comment: You are right! I did not even notice this in the error message. Thank you. Do you believe that this is due to IPv6 and Varchar(39) will solve this? I am using  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and in my case it shows ipv4 as a result.

Comment: Actually it was not an IPv6 problem, but rather a problem with added IPv4s from proxy servers and load balancers. Your solution did point me to the right direction though. Thank you. Here is a link to the related problem and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639205/remote-addr-returns-2-ipv4-instead-of-one

Comment: IPv6 is not the solution; it is another problem.  Just giving you another head's up.